# Method for determining the distribution of a 3D point cloud

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, multiple-comparisons

I am examining data sets which consist of 3D point clouds of potential variation from an origin.

Currently, I am analyzing each plane independent of the others, resulting in an $x$ histogram, $y$ histogram, and $z$ histogram.  I will also conduct tests for normality in each plane before I conduct additional analysis or reporting parameters such as capability (which are distribution dependent).

Is there a hypothesis test to test the 3D point cloud as a whole, or do I need to continue making assumptions based on each axis independently?

Comment: There are a lot of tools to deal with 3D datasets and even with higher dimensions, although they are hard to visualise in 2D. What do you want to test? That the points are aligned? Or lie in a plane? Or that they are clustered in one or more clusters? That the same information can be conveyed by using just two dimensions? Do you want to make predictions with your data?

Comment: Primarily, I want to test if the cloud is normally distributed in all dimensions simultaneously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your variables are distributed according to a [multivariate normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution), each variable is normally distributed, but the opposite is not true. Therefore, testing each independently is not enough to test the joint distribution.

There are several tests for multivariate normal. You can see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Multivariate_normality_tests or, in R, [MVN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MVN/vignettes/MVN.pdf) and [mvnormtest](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mvnormtest/mvnormtest.pdf) packages.